# react-multi-select-component stopPropagation onClose

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using the react-multi-select-component library. I've done the stopPropagation event when I click to open the the dropdown content, but I can't stop the propagation of an event if I close the dropdown content

Here is the render

```
return (
    <div onClick={(e) => e?.stopPropagation()} >
      <MultiSelect
        options={props.options}
        value={selected}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        onChange={onChange}
        labelledBy="Select"
      />
    </div>    
  );
```

Is that possible to handle the stopPropagation event on the close of the dropdown content?

Comment: It is not clear what (and why) you are trying to achieve. It works perfectly, See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-react-multi-select-component-t4690?file=/src/App.tsx). Please try to show me the problem. And, I would prefer https://react-select.com/home for creating dropdowns.

Comment: @AjeetShah i have this MultiSelect inside a th table. when a user click on this th, the sort function of that table will be activated. In this case, i had to add the e.stopPropagation in ordert to not activate the sort function. Now i have to do the same thing when i close the dropdown content, because if i close it outside the table is fine, but if i close it clicking inside a table on a row, then the selectRow function is activated. So i have to stop the selectrow event when i close the dropdown content.